# A (possible) Python scope issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope, pygame, global-variables

I cannot contribute my actual code (because it's over ten thousand lines), but I can give a brief summary of it.  Here it is, I give the symptoms later:

```
def calculate_stuffs():
    *global lots of stuff*
    *some other stuff*
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSLASH:
                try:
                    exec easygui.enterbox('Type command:')
                except:
                    print "Command crashed, or Easygui is not installed."
    *a lot of other stuff*
```

Here are some examples of when it works/fails:

- If I type a command that doesn't work, it returns the appropriate
  message.
- If I tell it to run a function, it works.
- If I tell it to read a variable (e.g. print a variable) it works.
- If I tell it to write to a variable, it doesn't do anything.  It
  doesn't even give the crashing message.  I made x a global variable,
  and it still does nothing if I say something like "x += 5".

I'm pretty sure this is an issue with scope, but I'm not sure.

If you need me to contribute more code, just ask.  When you find the answer, please explain why it works.  Thank you!

Comment: `*global lots of stuff*` Uh oh.

Comment: I know, right?  :\  Sorry about that.

Comment: I couldn't find a neat way around it.  They have to be in that function because of multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `global` within the `exec` statement as well, as `exec` has its own scope like a function:

```
x = 10

def foo():
    global x
    command = 'global x; x += 1; print x'
    try:
        exec command
    except:
        print "error"

print x
foo()
print x
```

will print:

```
10
11
11
```

Without `global x` within the `exec` statement it would print:

```
10
11
10
```

Comment: Do you mean in the for loop? ("for event in pygame.event.get():")

Comment: No. The code returned by `easygui.enterbox('Type command:')` must contain a `global` statement with all variables that should be treated global. Otherwise their scope will end after exec completes,

Comment: Oh.  That's... quite undesirable.  Is there a way I can keep it out of the command and keep it in the code?  That part of the program is there for debugging, and I wouldn't want to globalize stuff every time I want to type a command.

Comment: What is your code injected with `easygui.enterbox`? I highly depends on what that code does. You need to make it to store its local data somewhere. To a global variable, or using some method to save your data or something. It's the same as trying to access local variable of a function.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding.  Do you mean make the output from easygui global, then execute it?